# C++ error trying to return pointer that points to dynamic array in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am having some issues trying to return a pointer that points to a dynamic array in C++ while overloading the stream insertion operator. I am using Visual Studio 2017. Here is the relevant code. If you think it's necessary I'll post all of my code but I didn't want to make you read the whole thing when I'm only having problems with this one bit currently. Also, the assignment this is for requires me to use dynamic arrays, so please don't tell me to just use std::vector.

Student.h

```
    class Student
{
private:
string firstname;
string lastname;
unsigned int id;
unsigned int items_checkedout;
string *things = new string[items_checkedout];
}
```

Student.cpp

```
const string* Student::getthings()
{
    return things;
}
const string Student::getFirstName()
{
return firstname;
}

const string Student::getLastName()
{
    return lastname;
}

const int Student::getID()
{
return id;
}

unsigned int Student::CheckoutCount()
{
return items_checkedout;
}

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Student& stu)
{
    const string *things = stu.getthings;


out << stu.getID << " " << stu.getFirstName << " " << stu.getLastName << 
endl;
out << stu.CheckoutCount;
if (stu.CheckoutCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stu.CheckoutCount; i++)
    {
        out << things[i];
    }
}
}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

Error C3867 'Student::getthings': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member line 184

Error   C2276   '*': illegal operation on bound member function expression line 187

Error   C3867   'Student::CheckoutCount': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    line 188

"same thing, line 189

Error   C2296   '>': illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned int (__thiscall Student::* )(void)    line 189

Error   C2297   '>': illegal, right operand has type 'unsigned int (__thiscall  line 189

Error   C3867   'Student::CheckoutCount': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    line 191

Error   C2446   '<': no conversion from 'unsigned int &(__thiscall Student::* )(void)' to 'int' line 191

Comment: `stu.getthings;` isn't getthings a function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is beyond salvation.

Comment: I don't if I can go with beyond salvation, but the asker will certainly benefit more from [the guided learning of a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) than anything Stack Overflow is intended to offer.

Answer (score -1):

Your class definition lacks a `;` at the end, and *any* of the member functions you later define.

Your Student.cpp lacks a `#include "Student.h"` at the start.

Your Student.h lacks several standard `#include`s at the start.

These expressions `stu.getFirstName` are probably supposed to be like `stu.getFirstName()`.

Pick up a book on introductory C++.

Comment: How about `Student` declaration not having any of the member functions OP defines later?

Comment: @SergeyA: Indeed, that certainly doesn't help.